# Georeferencing CAD drawings

Tags: arcgis-desktop, import, performance, cad, spatial-adjustment

I am trying to Georeference CAD Drawing in ArcMap  by adding the Control Points. But it is taking a long time to load the CAD file. I could not do snapping and every time I hover over the mouse, it will load try to load. I tried to create spatial index (under properties) but it does not help much. I realized that it is slower when i have the base map i want the to in the georeference the cad file to. I only have one CAD Polylines layer turned on.

It is hard for me to Georefernce the CAD file in this way. Is there any way to make ArcMap read/load the CAD file faster?

Answer (score 2):

Simplify the DWG in Autocad as much as you can then convert to shapefile and use the Spatial Adjustment tools in ArcGIS instead.

Comment: I do not have Autocad. I can only work with ArcGIS. I tried to convert the Polylines to FC and deleted all the other lines that are not in used but it does not really help. Snapping is still almost impossible. Is there any other way to simplify the CAD Drawings?

Comment: This is just the nature of ArcGIS, snapping is slow with many complex vertices to snap to in the vicinity. Also working with very complex AutoCAD drawing files without the ability to modify them in AutoCAD can be difficult. Try turning snapping off and use spatial adjustment to reference the drawing approximately, then zoom in and do a second take at a much larger scale, this time with snapping turned on.  Unfortunately, with ArcGIS one needs to become a crafty master of workarounds as there is often no clear cut solution.

Comment: Instead of AutoCAD you can use nanoCAD (it's OS). You should use as simple CAD drawings as they can be in ArcGIS.